# C# service with MongoDB on OpenShift

Tags: c#, mongodb, openshift

I'm going to develop a c# service which needs access to MongoDB. I found it nice to have a base on openshift, but can't understand/find info if it's even possible to connect to Openshift MongoDB from non-openshift application? Let's say I have asp.net app on Azure and want to store data on Openshift. Is it possible and how to get connection url?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift then use a mongodb connection string in your azure application. Keep in mind the latency will be quite high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mongodb server would not be accessible outside of the OpenShift Infrastructure by direct connection.  You would either have to use the rhc port-forward command on the server running your c# application, or you would have to build an API on your OpenShift gear that would allow you to communicate with MongoDB.  You might be better off using https://mongolab.com/ or something like that, basically a DBaaS.

Comment: Thanks, as I thought, you can access only from inside.